# Supersized (jQuery plugin) only loads first slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

This is driving me nuts for the last 2 days.

I am correctly calling the `/supersized/core/js/supersized.core.3.2.1.js` script, and setting correctly the specifications, with all the images specified in the `slides` option... but only the first slide appears rendered.

**Script (simplified):**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $.supersized({
        slides : [ // Slideshow Images
            { image: "http://example.com/slide01.jpg" },
            { image: "http://example.com/slide02.jpg" },
            { image: "http://example.com/slide03.jpg" }
        ]
    });
});
```

**Rendered:**

```
<div id="supersized" style="visibility: visible;">
    <a target="_blank" class="activeslide">
        <img src="http://example.com/slide01.jpg" style="visibility: visible; width: 1439px; height: 1007.3px; left: 0px; top: -300px;">
    </a>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Core version only renders one at a time from the array, if you want a slideshow you need to use the Slideshow version. This can be found in the download package under the "slideshow folder".

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/download.html

Answer (score 0):

@buildinternet's [answer](http://twitter.com/#!/buildinternet/status/115778541131542528) (developers of the plugin):

> The Core version only renders one at a time from the array, if you want a slideshow you need to use the Slideshow version.

Comment: I used slide.html but its not working. Can you suggest me something else